# Get a wrong return type when using WebService

Tags: web-services

When I used a WebService, It  me a HTML type data, i.e the whole website HTML document.

I saw a code sample before, It's suppose to provide XML type.

I tried, can't figure what's going on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's a self-answered, common-sense question about a typo.

Comment: How on earth should we be able to help you here?

Comment: yes, it's a self-answered question. I just wanna mark it so that I keep it in mind. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was my parameters mistake.

Check your character spelling before doing other things when you're a newbie.